# Making a popup window between two websites

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

On our website we have a link to another page. This looks like this

```
<a href="URL" title="Title" class="thisClass">
  <img src="IMG"  width="20" border="0"/>
</a>
```

What I want is that when the link is clicked then a popup comes up with ex. this information:
“The page you are trying to enter has xx images and can take long time to load. Are you sure you want to continue”
xx is a variable that can be given from the website where the link is present.
Then there should of course be an OK and CANCEL button on the popup. If the OK button is clicked then the URL be loaded to the browser, if CANCEL is clicked then nothing should happen (return to original page)

The website is programmed in asp.net c#.

We are not interested in a new webpage, but just a simple javascript popup given the user a warning that due to xx number of images the webpage will be slow to load.

This webpage is used on an intranet site and we like to warn users when they enter a website that we expect will take long time to load.

Comment: On a side note, have you ever thought about simply using a *jQuery/javascript image gallery control* and only loading images as they are paged by the user?

Comment: A link on the page could open a bootstrap modal, the modal would have a button or link in it to the target page.  The delay involved in the user confirming the navigation though will probably negate any gain.  Just send them on to the page and the can always stop/back out if the wait is too long.  http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: We hoped also to be able to use this solution between pages where the loading time is not due to images. This is an internal network where we generate several reports and on other pages has huge collection of images. We would prefer to have the same solution on each. Hence we would like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jQuery UI Dialog (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or Twitter's Bootstrap Modal (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

I think the both solutions can do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="URL" title="Title" onclick="return confirm('The page you are trying to enter has xx images and can take long time to load. Are you sure you want to continue?');" class="thisClass">
 <img src="IMG"  width="20" border="0"/>
</a>
```

If you can do with the regular browsers' alert box, try this. Else you will have to resort to other jquery plugins to make it look more elegant that are mentioned on other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can user JqueryUi for this, this library includes Dialog which corresponds to your need.

This is the website :
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

And a sample of code that I find in this url :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

There is also example to manage confirmation (button OK and button CANCEL)

I hope that I help you ;)